# how i can search inside a lot of labels text and the label color would change to red

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Quick question how can I search text inside 60 `labels.text` and the label color will change. Thanks in advance and I appreciate the help last time

```
dim Nc as color = color.RED
dim Oc as color = Color.Black

'' i need to search in multiple labels.text using txt1.text if possible
if txt1.text = label1.text then
    laebl1.forecolor = Nc
End IF
```

Is there an easier way ?

Comment: ok thanx for that,, what u think

Comment: You need to create an array of labels and add all the labels in the array during Form_Load. Then you need to loop thru the array and compare the text of each label with the txt1.Text and change the color of the label if condition matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answer provided by `@Chetan_Ranpariya` and translating the code to `VB.Net` (with a small tweak) it would be something like this:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Public Class Form1
    Private lstControls As List(Of Tuple(Of TextBox, Label))
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstControls = New List(Of Tuple(Of TextBox, Label))
        lstControls.Add(Tuple.Create(TextBox1, Label1))
        lstControls.Add(Tuple.Create(TextBox2, Label2))
        lstControls.Add(Tuple.Create(TextBox3, Label3))
        lstControls.Add(Tuple.Create(TextBox4, Label4))
        lstControls.Add(Tuple.Create(TextBox5, Label5))
        lstControls.Add(Tuple.Create(TextBox6, Label6))
        lstControls.Add(Tuple.Create(TextBox7, Label7))
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each tuplePair As Tuple(Of TextBox, Label) In lstControls
            If tuplePair.Item1.Text = tuplePair.Item2.Text Then
                tuplePair.Item2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Basically for this you need a `List of Tuple` which is more efficient since every control has a pair. Inside the `For Each` statement you can include an `Else` clause to change the color to another one (I think this is to indicate the user the required fields on a form)
Give it a try and let me know your comments

Comment: i will thanx i will give it a try

Comment: ok so thats was good only i only have 1 txt1 and like 30 labels so far what should i use instead all textboxes

Comment: i dont need the txt to be in the list as it would be the search box

Comment: can i do that just for a part of the Text like instead of "3211" just "32" and then it will change the color for the label

Comment: Yes, change the declarations to List(Of Tuple(Of String, Label)) and useTuple(Of String, Label) on the loop

Comment: can you say more cause i think i cant get it to work

Comment: Can you be more explicit on your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an list of labels and add all the labels in the array during Form_Load. Then you need to loop thru the array and compare the text of each label with the txt1.Text and change the color of the label if condition matches.

Following is the sample code for this.

```
Public Partial Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Private labels As List(Of Label)
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        labels = New List(Of Label)()

        labels.Add(label1)
        labels.Add(label2)
        labels.Add(label3)
        labels.Add(label4)
        labels.Add(label5)
        labels.Add(label6)
        labels.Add(label7)
    End Sub

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        For Each label As Label In labels
            If textBox1.Text = label.Text Then
                label.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: this supposed to be in the upper (declartion) area or doesnt matter ,, cause it's not working

Comment: How it is not working? Are you able to loop thru the list of label? Did you try to debug and see if the loop is executed or not?

Comment: I think the problem is that the question is for VB.Net code and the answer is on C#

Comment: 3vts answer worked fine and this one i tried multiple times it keep saying an error  and var not defined  thanx a lot guys

Comment: The error is on the loop declaration it should be For Each var as Label in labels. And inside the loop change the label for var