# Change label text with an array

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I simply want to dynamically change my what label is currently edited through an array, to achieve as little code as possible.

This is what it looks like right now:

```
string[] poängLabels = new string[10];

for (int i = 3; i <= 9; i++)
{
    poängLabels[i] = ("label{0}.Text" + i);
}
```

Comment: So you have 10 lables and you want to get their Texts in to an array of 10 string ?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
poängLabels[i] = ((Label)this.Controls.Find("label" + i)).Text;
```

or

```
poängLabels[i] = ((Label)this.Controls["label" + i]).Text;
```

Comment: It won't accept ".Find" as an argument. Any idea why?

Comment: what's your .net framework version? and are the labels inside a container element?

Comment: @WalterKindblad Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: .NET Framework version is 4.0, and how do I know whether it's inside a container element? Sorry..

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer WinForms

Comment: can you try the second method I've added now?

Comment: The first one should work too (try adding `true` at the end maybe - [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Second doesn't give me syntax error at least, however it gives me an exception when I run the program "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: are the controls on the same form? and what does `this` refer to? it should refer to the current form. check that please.

Comment: @TahaPaksu They are, yes.

Comment: The best way to do this is to have the labels added in an array or list in Form_Load. And then iterate thru the list to get the values of each of the lables. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060238/how-i-can-search-inside-a-lot-of-labels-text-and-the-label-color-would-change-to/43060724#43060724

Comment: @TahaPaksu `this` is refering to the current form aswell.

Comment: I can't see a reason that this won't work. Maybe you have started `label` with capital letters, like `Label` but you're trying to reach `label`. this might be the cause.

Comment: @TahaPaksu The first syntax error mentioned is that it's missing the second argument in `Find`, a bool. However, adding either true or false just adds another syntax error.

Comment: What's the second one? If it's the object reference not set error, you should look at your label naming.

Comment: @TahaPaksu

`"Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'"`

Comment: Well, debug the result and look what's inside. if your desired label is inside the array, then try reaching it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to enumerate controls somehow, putting (or having them) in the array is one option:

```
var result = new { label1, label2, ... }.Select(label => label.Text).ToArray();
```